# With Webpack, is it possible to force warnings to be treated as errors?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

This is very common with other compiler toolchains like GCC via `-Werror`.

It's very useful for scenarios where you are required to follow strict guidelines and want to treat builds with warnings as errors and return a non-zero status code.

I couldn't find anything in Webpack's docs about this -- is it possible via the CLI?

Thanks!

(Latest version of Webpack v4.41.5 as of the time of writing this question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an NPM package that does this for you: [Webpack - Warnings To Errors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/warnings-to-errors-webpack-plugin)

There are a couple of things you can configure on your own:

```
stats: {
    logging: 'info', //  errors, warnings, and info messages
    warnings: true
},
output: {
    strictExportPresence: true // will throw error if import is missing, usually warning
}
```

Otherwise, create your own function for this:

```
if (compilation.warnings.length > 0) {
  compilation.errors = compilation.errors.concat(compilation.warnings);
  compilation.warnings = [];
}

compilation.children.forEach((child) => {
  if (child.warnings.length > 0) {
    child.errors = child.errors.concat(child.warnings);
    child.warnings = [];
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Joel -- this is exactly what I was looking for!